# Android Emulator error help me if you can?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

After displaying a new Dialog (actually it is a ContentView) my Android Emulator says "...App isn't responding" with a "Close App"- and a "Wait"-Button.

Is this probably something I screwed up or is this an Emulator related issue? Is there anything I can do to prevent or fix this?

I am a bit affraid that is my fault with something I did not handle correctly so that the App runs into issues on the real device not just the emulator.

I am working with VS 2022 and the "Pixel 6 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)" Emulator started in Debug of VS.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen even if your code is good. Once it happens, its likely to keep happening.

After you click "Wait", are you able to interact with the dialog? If so, then its likely just emulator has gotten messed up.
Fixes to try:
(1) Delete app from emulator, download it again. This helps ensure a clean start.
(2) IF still happening, Use Tools / Android / Android Device Manager. Select emulator, Stop it if running, do "Reset to Defaults" (just clears some internal settings) or "Factory Reset" (completely resets device to original factory condition). Quit and Restart Visual Studio.